# Separate Values from bars in horizontal bar chart by using mpandroidchart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am trying to make horizontal bar chart like this:

[image]

But I am unable to separate the values from bars as shown in the below image. If i use recyclerview then its difficult to align the text with the bars and the scrolling will cause issues too.

So please suggest me a way to show the values separately from the bars as shown below in the image.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the "difficult" thing you are saying? Could you put the code for your item in your recyclerView?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS How can i map each value from recycler view with the corresponding bar?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your doubt correctly or not, if I misunderstood the problem let me know and I'll remove the answer.

Let's say you have a `LinearLayout` with `orientation=horizontal` with some `weight`, then you add inside of it two `ProgressBar`, and let's say you add `id1` for the left one and `id2` for the right one.

So far so good, then in your adapter you can get that view, because is inside your `item_whatever.xml` and you can access to `id1` and `id2`, so the thing is, what to do now? As I'm seeing in the image you want to show a bar to the left and to the right, so, if I'm not wrong the bar to the left is printed when the value of the right is < 0, so in your adapter you can check this to print the "bar" (in this case the view you added inside the recyclerView).

Pseudocode :

```
if(number<0){
    yourViewForId1.setProgress(CalculateIt)
}else{
    yourViewForId2.setProgress(CalculateIt)
}
```

### Edit

This is in case you can not do it with your library, if you can you can use your library of course, is less work :)

I found this [YAxis](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/YAxis) perhaps is what you are looking for, and then you can create your item for your recyclerView and then add this in the middle of the name and the value.

Just try to instead of use this chart horizontally change the orientation and put it vertically if possible

Comment: so you mean to say instead of using mpandroidchart library i should use views and feed it with colors? If yes then how do i control that view width according to the value as for larger value width will be more and for smaller width will be less.

Comment: Well, I mean, if you know that in that library you can do what you want to achieve, you can use the library of course, but if it's something you can not do with that library you should create it by your own.

Comment: i totally agree with your point but the problem with your solution seems to be creating the dynamically sized bars

Comment: You could do a calculation knowing that progress is set to 100

Comment: The problem will be with the precision. If one value is 28.7 and another 28.9 then how i will show the float values with layout params as converting them into int will make both of them equal.

Comment: I think i need the XAxis code for that graph chart YAxis seems fine in the link you have shared of the wiki.

Comment: Yep, you can try it

Comment: I have tried by doing many tweakings in the bar chart but nothing is working out, see my this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59541099/set-the-negative-values-to-the-left-of-the-bars-in-horizontal-bar-chart/59543575?noredirect=1#comment105256325_59543575

Comment: Did you solve this question? May I delete my answer?